# Entity framework - dbcontext database sqlquery join multiple table in SQLite

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I can't execute SQL QUERY(string query)
ERROR MESSAGE:
The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive types.
HOW IT FIX????

```
Department class code here:
public class Department   
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public Int64 P_ID { get; set; }
}   
Person class code here:
public class PersonInfo    
{       
    [Key]
    public Int64 P_ID { get; set; }
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
    public string Register_Num { get; set; }
}

using (var db = new EntityContext())
        {
            try
            {
                int result = 0;
                string query = @"
                     SELECT P.P_ID, D.DepartmentName FROM PersonInfo AS P
                     INNER JOIN Department AS D ON P.P_ID = D.P_ID";

                var exists = db.Database
                .SqlQuery<Department>(query).ToList();

                foreach (var item in exists)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}", item));
                }                    
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: How have you defined the Department class?  If you had done db.Database.SqlQuery<string>(query) I would understand this but since you are using an object this is really interesting

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to map result set to Department Model class, so You need to return departmentid as well in with your sql query. Please note that all the column names should match exactly with the properties of you department class.